# Embedded Software - Why is 'const' necessary in lookup table?

Tags: c, memory, embedded, lookup, lookup-tables

I was just watching this video on LinkedIn Learning that was talking about 
Lookup tables and it mentioned that without the 'const' qualifier, the array will be allocated in RAM and initial assignment takes place during startup and the whole table would be stored twice - in RAM and ROM both.

Can someone explain this to me in a bit more detail? Why does it get stored twice? Does this mean that all variables/arrays without 'const' get stored twice? Would a switch case be better than lookup tables without const?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const` is not necessary due to C.  It depends on the compiler and processor.  What processor and compiler are you using?

Comment: What's unclear about the `const` qualifier you don't find in your textbook? Learning C from obscure online "tutorials" or YT videos is a bad idea.

Comment: The likely answer is simply that if you declare a lookup table (or any data structure) without `const` and provide initial data for it, then the system has to have both a copy of the initial data and separate space for the lookup table. This is because, since the table is not `const`, the compiler has to allow for the fact that something may change it (unless it can prove otherwise by examining all the code). So, to create the requested table, the compiler has to arrange for the program to have space for the table, and it has to fill in that space with the initial data. To do that,…

Comment: … the initial data has to be available. So there must be a copy of it somewhere. In contrast, if the table is defined with `const`, then the initial data itself can act as the table. There is merely one copy of the table containing the initial data, and it is only read, never modified, so a separate copy for the initial data is never needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. That was super clear!

Comment: The question is fine, voting to re-open. Textbooks will not likely tell much about how const works in RAM vs ROM on embedded systems. It is quite system-specific though, even though most microcontroller systems/compilers work similarly.

Comment: This link might be helpful: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microcontrollers have usually (except the Flashless ones) much more FLASH than RAM. It would be a waste to place the constant data in the RAM.

When you use the `const` keyword most toolchains place the data in the .rodata section which is located in the read only memory - FLASH. Some uC types (AVRs for example) need to use special mechanisms to access this data, for most modern ones there is almost no difference (fast uC need to slow down read and write operations using wait states as FLASH is slower than SRAM)

you can also force the `static const` automatic variables to be placed in ROM by using attributes and pragmas

(gcc) `static const char __attribute__((section(".rodata"))) x;` (sections may may have different names - check your toolchain documentation)

But it works only with the global variables - most implementations place automatic `const` variables on the stack which is located in RAM

## EDIT

The `static const` may be stored as well in the ROM only. But several years ago I had a bad experience with one of the uC gcc branches. To make sure - check what your toolchain is doing with this variables.

So the `const` is not **necessary** for lookup tables but it is logical to save the the (usually) very limited resource - the SRAM.

Comment: Global variables are permanent. In the case of automatic variables, the stack memory is recycled on function exit, so they are not as greedy on SRAM.

Comment: Thanks. @P__J__

1) What I'm still confused about is when "const" is not used, why is the array stored in both RAM and ROM? Can you please shed some light on that?

2) And about the global variables part - if it was a local variable, it would probably overflow the stack as it needs to be allocated on every call right? I guess using a static qualifier would solve that. Unless the issue is something else.

Comment: @ShantanuMhapankar an initialised variable in SRAM must be present in ROM too, because its data must be copied from *somewhere*. As for using the `static` qualifier for an automatic variable, that's the same memory use as making it a global variable, and yes, an initialised automatic variable will need its data copying from ROM on every function call. The effect of a local variable that is `static` is that it persists in the same memory space as a global, but is private to the function.

Comment: @WeatherVane not so greedy but if you have 1k SRAM stack is also very limited

Comment: Interesting DV. Did I write something wrong or someone is just frustrated

Comment: @WeatherVane my dictionary switched to Esperanto (btw I did not install it as do not speak Esperanto ). / I did not suspect you :).

Comment: I have not voted, but this answer does not address the question. The first paragraph states it would be a waste to put constant data in RAM. this does not speak to whether a lookup table is placed in RAM if it is not marked `const`. The second paragraph says when `const` is used, most toolchains place the data in a read-only section. This does not speak to why a lookup table not marked `const` would be in both. The third paragraph says the preceding paragraph was only for global variables. (This is false; the issue is lifetime, not scope.) It again does not speak to the question.…

Comment: … And, finally, the last paragraph, states a conclusion but still does not speak to the question.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane that makes sense to me now.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - that depends on the implementation. Some gcc uC implementations were placing static local variables in the RAM. I have discovered it several years ago and reported it (AVR branch). I did not check recently because knowing this issue just in case I am declaring `const` variables which should be located in the FLASH in the global scope. So in the real life theoretical knowledge is not always applicable. I do not use AVR for years anymore and I will check how the ARM gcc behaves now

Comment: "_it works only with the global variables_" ... for local variables use `static const` to render them ROMable.

Comment: @Clifford read my comment. Maybe gcc has sorted it out by now but several years ago it did not ROM it.

Comment: @P__J__ : Indeed YMMV - I was very careful to state that it is ROMable rather then _will be_ ROM'ed.  My experience with ARMCC is that it is stored in ROM.  All previous comments referred to `static` rather then `static const` - you need both.  That said my experience is with C++ compilation where `const` on its own has different semantics.

Comment: @Clifford I have edited my answer.